# Android JB 4.2.2 and Monkeyrunner script to make call

Tags: command, adb, phone-call, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am using Jelly Bean 4.2.2 on my device and trying to make a call using Monkeyrunner script.
I am using the below code which was working on ICS very well but in JB, it doesn't type the phone number in the edit text box once the key dialer screen is opened.. Does anyone experience this issue?

```
device.startActivity(component='com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity')

device.type("8888888888")
```

BR
Srini

Comment: The following works on JB so I am not stuck atleast. Now curioes why the above command doesn't work on JB.

Comment: device.startActivity(action ='android.intent.action.CALL', data= 'tel:8888888888')

Answer (score 0):

The intent alternative is the correct one for many cases, however if you really want to simulate a real user dialing a number you can use this [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) script slightly edited from  *autogenerated* to add the `dialNumber` method and other minor things:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/shebang monkeyrunner -plugin $AVC_HOME/bin/androidviewclient-$AVC_VERSION.jar @!
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2013-05-15 by Culebra v0.9.8

                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

def dialNumber(number):
    print "dialing", number
    digits = [zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine]
    for d in number:
        if d in ['-', ' ']:
            continue
        digits[int(d)].touch()
        vc.sleep(0.5)
    dial.touch()

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.startActivity(component='com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity')
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, autodump=False)
vc.dump(window='-1')

back = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('backspace')
one = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('one')
two = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('two')
three = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('three')
four = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('four')
five = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('five')
six = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('six')
seven = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('seven')
eight = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('eight')
nine = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('nine')
star = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('star')
zero = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('zero')
pound = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('pound')
dial = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('dial')
search = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('search')
moreOptions = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise('More options')


dialNumber("800-555-1234")
```